How do I set Liveslak to be persistent?
I’m currently using Liveslak as a USB operating system. Is there a way to configure Liveslak to retain all user data and applications upon shutdown, rather than deleting them?
Thank you for your assistance! I greatly appreciate your help.

I think the question then becomes: why use liveslack if you don't want the "live" component? What's the advantage over installing a regular slackware e.g. onto a USB drive?

@MarcusMüller I only own a singular USB stick. Installing Slackware upon the USB would require that I own two USB sticks. Thank you.

no, it wouldn't; that's a fallacy.

I'm not a user of Liveslak, but found Slackware Live Edition which contains:

How to create a persistent USB stick from the ISO?
The ISO can be burnt to a DVD or copied to USB stick using ‘dd’ or just plain ‘cp’, but that will give you a read-only medium because all changes to the Live OS are in fact written to your computer’s RAM and lost when you reboot.
Use the ‘iso2usb.sh‘ script to create a Live OS on the USB device with persistence.

The question doesn't say how the live image was copied to the USB stick, but if dd or cp was used rather than the iso2usb.sh script the result would be no persistence.
See also Transfering ISO content to USB stick in the Slackware documentation about the iso2usb.sh script.

From a comment:

Can I use "iso2usb.sh" while running Liveslak from a USB that I intend to make persistent? – user2231142

Looking at the iso2usb.sh script shows it must be provided with the Full path to the ISO image file -i argument:
# More sanity checks:
if [ -z "$SLISO" ]; then
  echo "*** You must specify the Live ISO filename (option '-i')!"
  exit 1
fi

As a result, the script is not designed to be used on Liveslak running from a USB which is intended to be made persistent.

Thank you very much; this is extremely helpful. Can I use "iso2usb.sh" while running Liveslak from a USB that I intend to make persistent?

@user2231142 I have updated the answer to try and address your comment.

Thank you so much! This is immensely helpful. I immensely appreciate the help.
